# Change width of progress bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I try  change width of bootstrap progress bar with java script but don't worked.I wrote this code in head section. Please advice.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar").setAttribute("style", "width:50%");
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar").style.width = "width:50%";
```

Html :

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.width = "50%";` OR `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar"),function(elem){ elem.style.width="50%" });`

Comment: I use this java script code into onload of body tag. I test this way but don't worked

Comment: How many elements are there having class as `progress-bar` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** will return a list of nodes, you should specify the index of the one you want to change :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].setAttribute("style", "width:50%");
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.width = "50%";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked correctly .  Is this code works in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use `document.querySelector` - it returns single element
[All major browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

And this is incorrect

```
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar").style.width = "width:50%";
//must be
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar").style.width = "50%";
```

checkout demo below

```js
var percent = 10;
document.querySelector(".progress-bar").style.width = percent + "%";
function increase(){
  percent = percent > 90 ? 10 : percent + 10;
  document.querySelector(".progress-bar").style.width = percent + "%";
}
```

```css
.progress{
  background: red;
  padding: 3px;
}
.progress-bar{
  background: blue;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<button onclick="increase()">increase</button>
```